# Connect to Mainframe Server issue

Tags: ftp, jobs, mainframe, filezilla

I am trying to Connect to a Mainframe Server and submit a job.

I have tried various options i.e. Jenkins plugin,  Writing a Java program, Using Widows command prompt. It seems I am getting stuck at one point. It seems to be waiting for the welcome message and timeout after 20 seconds of inactivity.

**Using Command Prompt:**

```
ftp> open  <IP Address> 23
Connected to <IP Address>.
Connection closed by remote host.
```

**Using A sample Java Program:**

It gets stuck at  ftp.connect(serverName,23);  for a very long time and then throws the below error.

```
    java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for initial connect reply
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP._connectAction_(FTP.java:393)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._connectAction_(FTPClient.java:924)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._connectAction_(FTPSClient.java:207)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:183)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:203)
at com.ivl.util.FileTransferProtocol.main(FileTransferProtocol.java:60)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.net.io.CRLFLineReader.readLine(CRLFLineReader.java:58)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:314)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:294)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP._connectAction_(FTP.java:387)
... 5 more
```

I am trying to use Filezilla as well, here is the filezilla log set at debug level.

```
 12:38:36   Status: Connecting to <IP Address>:23...
12:38:36    Status: Connection established, initializing TLS...
12:38:36    Trace:  CTlsSocket::Handshake()
12:38:36    Trace:  CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
12:38:36    Trace:  TLS handshake: About to send CLIENT HELLO
12:38:36    Trace:  TLS handshake: Sent CLIENT HELLO
12:38:36    Trace:  CTlsSocket::OnSend()
12:38:36    Trace:  CTlsSocket::OnRead()
12:38:36    Trace:  CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
12:38:36    Trace:  CTlsSocket::OnRead()
12:38:36    Trace:  CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
12:38:37    Trace:  CTlsSocket::OnRead()
12:38:37    Trace:  CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
12:38:37    Trace:  TLS handshake: Received SERVER HELLO
12:38:37    Trace:  TLS handshake: Processed SERVER HELLO
12:38:37    Trace:  TLS handshake: Received CERTIFICATE
12:38:37    Trace:  TLS handshake: Processed CERTIFICATE
12:38:37    Trace:  TLS handshake: Received SERVER HELLO DONE
12:38:37    Trace:  TLS handshake: Processed SERVER HELLO DONE
12:38:37    Trace:  TLS handshake: About to send CLIENT KEY EXCHANGE
12:38:37    Trace:  TLS handshake: Sent CLIENT KEY EXCHANGE
12:38:37    Trace:  TLS handshake: About to send FINISHED
12:38:37    Trace:  TLS handshake: Sent FINISHED
12:38:37    Trace:  CTlsSocket::OnRead()
12:38:37    Trace:  CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
12:38:37    Trace:  TLS handshake: Received FINISHED
12:38:37    Trace:  TLS handshake: Processed FINISHED
12:38:37    Trace:  TLS Handshake successful
12:38:37    Trace:  Protocol: TLS1.2, Key exchange: RSA, Cipher: AES-256-GCM, MAC: AEAD
12:38:37    Status: Verifying certificate...
12:38:37    Status: TLS connection established, waiting for welcome message...
12:38:37    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
12:38:57    Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
12:38:57    Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(2050)
12:38:57    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(2114)
12:38:57    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(2114)
12:38:57    Error:  Could not connect to server
12:38:57    Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(2114)
12:38:57    Status: Waiting to retry...
12:39:00    Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(64)
12:39:00    Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(64)
```

I am able to use Mocha TN3270 or any mainframe emulators to connect to the same server. Which is weird.

[Connected using Mocha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKnZF.gif)

I am at loss here as to what might be causing this and how to fix the problem, My aim is to connect and submit a batch job programmatically, I can use a batch file , java program etc. so far all my tries seems to futile.

Comment: Terminal sessions are not file transfer protocol (FTP) sessions. You'll need specialised software to talk to a mainframe (details will depend on details of the mainframe and how it is configured).

Comment: If you are allowed to access that system, someone will give you all the information for how you will be able to access that system, No-one here can help you.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to connect using any  mainframe emulators e.g. Mocha and create and trigger Jobs, That works.  Thats all the info i got. Now what I want is to be able to trigger the same Job in a CI environment using Jenkins, for that I am trying the Java or CMD

Comment: So you have to telll your support people, not us.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you, you're trying to connect with FTP to port 23? That's not the port that FTP usually uses. Port 23 may be where your TN3270 connects to, but FTP probably connects to the normal port 21 and Telnet/SSH probably connects to a different port--you'll have to ask your friendly local sysprog what port.

Actually, if you tell them what you're trying to do they will probably be able to help you out or possibly tell you that it's not allowed. Either way you should more quickly get a real answer specific to your environment.

Comment: If the JESINTERFACELEVEL parameter of the Job Entry Subsystem is set correctly, and all the attendant security is in place, what the OP desires can be accomplished.  As has been pointed out to the OP multiple times, they must contact their support staff.